# Bootstrap FileInput handler doesn't get input values

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table and an input that changes its value depending on the selected row, when the page loads, the input has the value "" because no row is selected yet, but if you select row 5 for example, the input shows 5, that part works perfect.

```
<input id="input1"/>
<input id="fileupload" type="file" />
```

Now I have a fileinput that calls handler to upload the file you want with a parameter that is equal to the value of input1, the problem is that the parameter is always equal to "" even when you can clearly see that the input has changed its value.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#fileupload").fileinput({
        uploadUrl: 'http://localhost:63043/Presentacion/CoordinadoraHandler.ashx?value='+$("#input1").val(),
        'showRemove': true,
        'showUpload': true,
        'showPreview': false
    });
});
```

I dont know what I'm doing wrong, why the value is always "" and not the current input value.

On codebhind I use `string value= context.Request["value"];` but I get always ""

Answer (score 0):

try this one and visit this [Page](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) for more information. You can get information about your files however you like.

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                  f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                  f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                  '</li>');
    }
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>
```